# Extract HOG from a single pixel using VLFEAT

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, vlfeat, mser

I'm trying to extract points of interest to perform an image registration of clinical images. I've detected [MSER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) from an image "I" using `vl_mser`:

```
[R, F] = VL_MSER(...)
```

which returns a region of seeds `R` and ellipsoids `F`.

Now I would like to calculate Hog from the ellipsoids' center using `vl_hog`. However, the input of `vl_hog` is an image, and I don't know how to extract a [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) from a single pixel (center of ellipsoids).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB has a function [detectMSERFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html) for detecting MSER regions, and a function [extractHOGFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html) for computing the HOG descriptors at given locations.